# NullReferenceException when iterating over generic list

Tags: c#, list, foreach, nullreferenceexception

I read alot about generic lists and the reasons for NullReferenceExceptions, but in my case it looks like I've done everything right, but still get the famous error.

I initialize a generic List at the top of a class:

```
List<CustomType> customTypes = new List<CustomType>();
```

then I add some items to the list and of course I debug the count and names to make sure there is no null entry. Without touching the list any further, I call this method:

```
string newString = GetString("some string", customTypes);
```

Its structure looks like this:

```
public string GetString(string value, List<CustomType> cTypes)
{
    // in my case I add two items to the customTypes list, when the form is loaded
    Console.WriteLine(customTypes.Count); // output: 2
    Console.WriteLine(cTypes.Count); // output: 2

    foreach(CustomType ct in cTypes)
    {
        // All I do within this foreach is just debugging
        Console.WriteLine("Current item: " + ct.ToString()); // NullReferenceException ct seems to be null
    }
    return value;
}
```

I don't know why it is throwing an error. Any idea?

**EDIT**: Actually the first thing in the foreach loop is: `Console.WriteLine("Current item: " + ct.ToString())` // which throws the error and tells me that ct is null, but how can this be? The console shows me that there are items in both lists?!

Comment: That must be somewhat oversimplified since it would never cause that exception.

Comment: It means that `cTypes` is null.

Comment: Please post some more relevant code... as it stands your problem is not reproducible from your sample

Comment: Are you sure that whatever `{manipulate string}` is doing is not where the exception is actually thrown? A stack trace would be useful.

Comment: I updated the question, added some comments to the method. One thing I recognized is that the actual error points at the `Console.WriteLine("in foreach loop");` but I guess that's normal?!